# "Мне наплевать на ...". Why is it acceptable to use an infinitive verb?

Tags: грамматика, impersonal

> Мне **наплевать** на тех, кто сейчас занимает мое место.

This expression seems to bear all the hallmarks of an impersonal construction, so I wonder why the 3rd-person singular "наплюёт" is not used here.

On another note: Are there other expressions that take an infinitive verb in a similar fashion?

Comment: If "наплюёт" (3rd p. sg.) were used, it'll sound as if somebody else doesn't care about them, but the infinitive makes it clear that it's I who don't care. Besides, "наплюёт" can't be used impersonally.

Comment: in your earlier question ["Тебе и решать"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15808/how-to-interpret-the-grammatical-construction-of-тебе-и-решать) the second point was addressed by **artptr**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the forms of an **impersonal sentence** formed with the **independent infinitive** which serves as a predicate and a hidden subject of a pronoun in the dative. The infinitive corresponds to present time, though grammatically it doesn't show tense. If you want to refer the action to the past, you should use "было"
and for future "будет".

> Зачем ему **было уезжать**?
>
> Вам **наплевать будет** на него.

**Наплевать** is used idiomatically, meaning "все равно", I don't care.

Comment: "Откуда мне **знать**, что ... ?": Is this one of those impersonal sentences? If so, how should I paraphrase it for the past tense: "How could I have known that ..."?

Comment: Откуда мне было знать...